# Eloquent Javascript 2nd. Chapter 4. Computing Correlation. Lycanthrope’s log - [IndexOf Defined] Pt 1

Tags: javascript, eloquent

I am currently going through Eloquent Javascript and came upon the were-squirrel example. There is a piece of code we are using to create a table/matrix for when Jacques(the subject of the problem) turns into a squirrel. It reference's a journal we made earlier.

here is the code.

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
 return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
    table[index] += 1;
  }
  return table;
}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
// → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

Now I understand what the function tableFor does and how it references the event from the variable journal (we have the journal as separate file and reference) but I don't understand the != 1 and returning inside the function tableFor. I assume we want to determine if this event we are looking for returned true if this is the case why are we not making an "if" entry? or perhaps == 0, or == 1? Am I missing something?

If someone could explain everything about

```
return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
```

That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using the book name and chapter number as the title isn't terribly informative as to what you're asking. You might want to streamline this a little to emphasize the actual question.

Comment: You probably want to read up on what Array.prototype.indexOf actually does.

Comment: @sphanley - I have changed the title to highlight the question. I kept the chapter and book name, but I'll make sure to put more detail of the question , you're right, just a chapter and book name is not adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the OP asks has two sides:

1. How `indexOf` function works
2. Why does it not use `if` statement when it is comparing

First question was answered by the accepted answer. However, second one was not.

The OP seems to understand it as he accepted the answer but for the other viewers of this question, it may still be unclear.

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
 return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}
```

is equivalent of below:

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
     if (entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1)
         return true;
     else
         return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The indexOf function returns a positive number (or zero) if and only if there is an occurrence of whatever is passed in. If there is not an occurrence indexOf returns -1. The hasEvent function will return true if the event has occurred, otherwise it will return false.